# Unable to get method doc using GroovyRootDocBuilder

Tags: groovy, groovydoc

I am trying to get the class doc using GroovyRootDocBuilder

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("publicScope", "true");
    properties.setProperty("protectedScope", "true");
    properties.setProperty("packageScope", "true");
    properties.setProperty("privateScope", "true");
    GroovyRootDocBuilder rootDocBuilder = new GroovyRootDocBuilder(null, null, null, properties);
    String filename = "D:\\git\\pdf-enricher\\src\\main\\groovy\\com\\pdfflow\\enricher\\operations\\PageOperations.groovy"
    String src = ResourceGroovyMethods.getText(new File(filename));
    String file = GroovyDocTool.getFile(filename);
    Map<String, GroovyClassDoc> ret = rootDocBuilder.getClassDocsFromSingleSource("com.pdfflow.enricher.operations", src, file);
    System.out.println(ret);
```

I am getting only Class doc and constructor doc, I am not able to retreive any information for method and field doc.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake... i was passing src and file at wrong order in getClassDocsFromSingleSource